# How to check a cell in excel integer or not in apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

I am using apache POI to read excel.i  have  a requirement that the the value in the excel should only be integer. I have done this

```
if(cell.getCellType()==XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC)
```

but it is applicable for all numeric values. But i want to check only for integer.Plese help.I dont find any thing in this XSSFCell to check integer.

Comment: Can you not just fetch the numeric cell value then, which is a double, and test if that number is a whole number or not?

Comment: ya thats a way but i am asking if POI has something in it..

Comment: Nope, all depends on your rules. For example, if someone writes in `1.25` to a cell, then formats that to be an integer so it displays as just `1`, do you count that as an integer or not? Your business rules are likely too specific for a general case, so you just need to write 3 lines of code!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the cell value and check if it's value changes when you round it. It doesn't use the POI library, but get's the job done:

```
Double numericCellValue = cell.getNumericCellValue();
if(Math.floor(numericCellValue) == numericCellValue){
    // It's an integer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try and add another condition

```
if(cell.getCellType()==XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC)
{
    if(cell.getNumberCellValue instanceof Integer)
       do something

}
```

Comment: That won't work - the value is always returned as a double as per the [Javadocs](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getNumericCellValue%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

```
    Cell value=cols.next();
    if(value.getCellType()==CellType.NUMERIC)
    {
                        
       System.out.println((int)value.getNumericCellValue());
                    
    }
It will check is cellType is numeric which includes double also. But once confirmed, it will type cast it into numeric value.
```